# UIScrollView connection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have `ParentviewController` say VC_1.
Inside VC_1, I have a `scrollview` and a `childViewcontroller`(as subviews of VC_1). Now inside `childViewController` I have another `scrollview`.How do I connect the two `scrollviews`.

Comment: Connect them in what way? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: when i scroll the one in the parent.. the scrollview in the child view controller should also move.

Comment: it only makes sense to scroll one scroll view at a time, as otherwise the content would move glitchy under the user's finger